# Deserialize Object into a class does not work

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

I am trying to set a class for a token using DeserializeObject from the json object i get back from my api. However when i run the below code it sets all the values to null or 0, not the result i am getting from the api.

cs code

```
var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(resultString);
```

class

```
public class Token : ContentPage
{
    public int StaffID { get; set; }
    public string TokenApi { get; set; }
    public string StaffForename { get; set; }
    public string StaffSurname { get; set; }
    public string StaffEmail { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryStaffRoleID { get; set; }
}
```

JSON response

```
"{\"code\":201,\"status\":\"Success\",\"message\":\"Object found\",\"data\":{\"StaffID\":14,\"StaffSurname\":\"Test\",\"StaffForename\":\"Test\",\"StaffEmail\":\"test@test.com\",\"PrimaryStaffRoleID\":5,\"TokenApi\":\"testToken\"}}"
```

Comment: what you mean by doesn't works ?

Comment: It keeps setting each value to null or 0, even tho i have the data in my json response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly the data which you are trying to map is inside another property in your json called `Data` and secondly your json does not have a property with name `Token`

The problem actually is you are not using the correct type that reflects your json, means you don't have correct c# type which would get mapped to json, you can generate correct types using [json2charp.com](http://json2csharp.com/) , the correct classes for it are :

```
public class Data
{
    public int StaffID { get; set; }
    public string StaffSurname { get; set; }
    public string StaffForename { get; set; }
    public string StaffEmail { get; set; }
    public int PrimaryStaffRoleID { get; set; }
    public string TokenApi { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public int code { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
    public Data data { get; set; }
}
```

Now deserializing using `RootObject` as type parameter would work perfectly fine like:

```
var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(resultString);
```

A more good option is to use [QuickType.IO](https://quicktype.io/) which would even generate code for you in c# or any other language that they are supporting.

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze the JSON that you posted, the object that you're trying to Deserialize is inside the "data" property of your json.

[image]

I suggest you creating a class to represent the JsonResponse with a `Data` property. This will be your `Token`

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieved a string that match this object

```
public string code {get;set;}
public string Success {get;set;} ...
```

And Token is matching data in json, so

```
var post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Token>(resultString.data);
```

would be better.